# ActionScript 3: Tween stops mid animation...Probably the garbage collector

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have been relentlessly trying to get my tweens in ActionScript 3 to work correctly, however with reaserch I have founf that the cause for the freezing mid animation is because of the garbage collector... I have tried both these methods, and have tried putting it in my document class, and yet it still happens to freeze randomly. It looks like I may have to go for something like tween lite, however something so simple shouldn't be so hard...

Attempt 1:

```
function createScrollingMC(mc:MovieClip, stageLeft:int, stageRight:int, durationSecs:int) {
    var scrollingTween01:Tween;
    var multiplyer:int = 100;
    scrollingTween01 = new Tween(mc, "x", None.easeNone, stageLeft - mc.width, stageRight + mc.width, durationSecs * multiplyer, true);
    scrollingTween01.looping = true;
}

createScrollingMC(Cloud_01, 0, 1024, 1);
createScrollingMC(Cloud_02, 0, 1024, 2);
createScrollingMC(Cloud_03, 0, 1024, 3);
createScrollingMC(Cloud_04, 0, 1024, 4);
```

Attempt 2:

```
var scrollingTween01:Tween;

function createScrollingMC(mc:MovieClip, stageLeft:int, stageRight:int, durationSecs:int) {

    var multiplyer:int = 100;
    scrollingTween01 = new Tween(mc, "x", None.easeNone, stageLeft - mc.width, stageRight + mc.width, durationSecs * multiplyer, true);
    scrollingTween01.looping = true;
}

createScrollingMC(Cloud_01, 0, 1024, 1);
createScrollingMC(Cloud_02, 0, 1024, 2);
createScrollingMC(Cloud_03, 0, 1024, 3);
createScrollingMC(Cloud_04, 0, 1024, 4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-using the Tween instance scrollingTween01. It's a good thing, but you start using it before the last one finished tweening. After you re-assign it, it will stop animation of the previous one and this has nothing to do with GC.

Create new instances for the Tween class and that should solve your problem.

```
function createScrollingMC(mc:MovieClip, stageLeft:int, stageRight:int, durationSecs:int)
{
    var multiplyer:int = 100;
    var tween = new Tween(mc, "x", None.easeNone, stageLeft - mc.width, stageRight + mc.width, durationSecs * multiplyer, true);
    tween.looping = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, whilst creating the tween inside the function did not seem to work for me, your suggestion of creating a new tween did however work when I created it outside the function, this led to me creating 4 functions for each movieclip, however it works, and I plan to simplify the function better. 

Thanks for your help :D